# Calculating number of lines with N or greater bits set

Tags: algorithm, math, formula, excel-formula, multicast

I'm looking into IP multicasting at the moment, and determining the number of unique multicast groups required to address all possible combinations of N hosts.

For instance, if we have 3 end hosts (A, B, C), a total of 4 multicast groups would need to be created to enable all possible combinations of these hosts to be addressed (AB, AC, BC, ABC), excluding instances where 1 or 0 hosts are being addressed.

As far as I can tell, the number of unique groups excluding instances where 1 or 0 hosts are being addressed can be expressed as [2^N - (N + 1)], where N = the number of hosts.

However, I'm interested in looking at how many groups exist when only at least a certain percentage of systems are addressed.

For instance, if we had 5 systems, we would have a total of 26 multicast groups. However, if we excluded groups where 3 or fewer systems were being addressed (only looking at groups were 4 or all systems are addressed), we would have only 6 groups. I can determine this by hand, as shown below.

Is there a formula I can use to calculate this instead? So, if we have N hosts and want to create only multicast groups which include Y hosts or greater, it means we have Z multicast groups. In the above example, Y = 4, Z is determined to be 6.

Any assistance or feedback is always appreciated

```
1 with 0 bits set
00 - 00000

5 with 1 bit set
01 - 00001
02 - 00010
04 - 00100
08 - 01000
16 - 10000

10 with 2 bits set
03 - 00011
05 - 00101
06 - 00110
09 - 01001
10 - 01010
12 - 01100
18 - 10010
20 - 10100
17 - 10001
24 - 11000

10 with 3 bits set
07 - 00111
11 - 01011
13 - 01101
14 - 01110
19 - 10011
21 - 10101
22 - 10110
25 - 11001
26 - 11010
28 - 11100

5 with 4 bits set
15 - 01111
23 - 10111
27 - 11011
29 - 11101
30 - 11110

1 with 5 bits set
31 - 11111
```

Comment: "However, if we excluded groups where 3 or fewer systems were being addressed (only looking at groups were 4 or all systems are addressed), we would have only 5 groups." -- wouldn't that be 6 groups (5 with 4 systems plus 1 with 5 systems)?

Comment: @hatchet Yep -- good catch. I'll update my question.

Comment: This topic is covered here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Treating this like a combination problem should help. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination

Out of N bits you want to know the sum of combinations where you have Y to N bits set.

Something like this pseudo-code:

```
for k from Y..N
  total += (N choose k)
```

Where `N choose k` can be calculated as `N! / (k! * (N-k)!)`

For your example you would get:

```
5 choose 4 = 5
5 choose 5 = 1
--------------
     total = 6
```

Comment: Your formula for calculating `N choose k` appears wrong?:

http://bit.ly/KCfPHZ vs. http://bit.ly/M4U671

Comment: @BSchlinker Needs parentheses for the computer, `N! / (k!*(N-k)!)`. Works without parentheses for humans knowing the formula ;)

Comment: I always evaluate using PEMDAS moving left to right. Seems like the parentheses are required regardless, no? (Then again, I guess there is no set standard: http://bit.ly/fbEZEz)

Comment: @BSchlinker I updated the formula to include parentheses for clarity. Since I've never used a programming language with a factorial operator (at least that I'm aware of) I wasn't thinking about the order of operations.

Answer (score 3):

```
Sum[i=0 to N] N{C}i = Sum of all combinations of i hosts out of N hosts = 2^N
--- [1] 
Sum[i=0 to Y] N{C}i = Sum of all combinations of multicast groups with Y or fewer hosts, including single hosts. 
--- [2]
```

You are looking for ([1] - [2]).

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the notation N{C}i..
[Edit] It appears that is what you are performing the summation over? Could you please give an example of the use of your formula to remove any confusion from my end?

Comment: N{C}i = N choose i. In your example, 5 choose 2 = 10. If you Google 5 choose 2, it will even calculate the answer for you.

Comment: All combinations of choosing i hosts out of a total of N hosts. The wikipedia link provided by @hatchet will give you exact details.

Comment: The sum for all `i` from `0` to `N` is `2^N`, since `N choose 0` is `1`.

Comment: @DanielFischer Updated my response on your feedback.